# Prime faces Data table (V 3.4)  Sort Column Without Using icon

Tags: css, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I'm using primefaces data table in my application,as per request from business users they want to sort by clicking on the column header not the '<>' Sorting icons,but '/\' or '/' icons still can be visible during sorting.how to customize primefaces css property ? i tried to modify this css property but couldn't get proper results.

```
 .ui-icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background-image:none ;
display: block;
text-indent: -99999px;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat:repeat;

}
```

Comment: try this , `jQuery('#yourTableId th .ui-sortable-column-icon').css({"display":"none"});`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel,I'm able to hide the icon,but need to always click on the corner where it placed before.how to make the column header sortable ?

Comment: Click anywhere in header and it will be sorted, icon is just the visualizer not the target of the sort event. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSorting.jsf

Comment: @BernadAli as Cagatay Civici said , the just click anywhere in the header and it will be sorted , unless you did something there...

Comment: Thanks Civici & Danial- yeah i'll check with my datatable column headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this in your CSS file

```css
#yourTableId th .ui-sortable-column-icon{
    display : none;
}
```

or, instead, place this in your JS file

```
jQuery('#yourTableId th .ui-sortable-column-icon').css({"display":"none"});
```

Comment: Adding: #yourTableId th .ui-icon-triangle-1-n { display: inline-block !important; } and #yourTableId th .ui-icon-triangle-1-s !important; } to the css will allow the /\ and the \/ to be displayed on sort, with the unsorted caret hidden.